# Bash script launching bash script with ends in exec

Tags: bash, execute-command

In one script (A) I set some env variables, check for presence of other required binaries and at that end `exec <mybinary>`.
Now, new script appeared (B) which in similar way starts other binary. With exec at the end. I cannot modify its content (other repo, other author, other project, etc).
When I start B from A before **mybinary** - **mybinary** is not executed.
I need this what script B provides for **mybinary** to execute properly.
I tried `$(./script_B)` and `/bin/bash -c "./script_B"`. No success.

I say even further:
When I `ps -as | grep <theirbinary` and `ps -ax | grep <scriptA>` - BOTH have the same PID.

How to start other script (B) so that its **exec** won't steal/block/overwrite script A further execution?

PS: Example script:

Script A

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/pathA:/pathC
> ...
> ${THIS_DIR}/scriptB.sh
> exec ${THIS_DIR}/mybinary

Script B (I cant modify it)

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/pathA:/pathC
> ...
> exec ${THIS_DIR}/theirbinary

Comment: Try to run the last line without `exec`, in other words; `${THIS_DIR}/mybinary`

Comment: OK, the other script is run before your `exec` command. And you cannot modify it?! Then my tip in the previous comment won't work. `exec` replaces the calling script. But maybe if you add a script level (call a script that calls the script B)? Maybe the calling script is not killed. Or you can push calling script B into the background with `&` or push what should be executed after script B into the background with `&` **before** calling script B, and make it wait until script B has finished (check its PID), if that is necessary.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Besides `ps - as` does not work. What version of bash you are using?